# Wifi network disappears from list and/or can't connect

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

I have an Acer laptop with Windows 10, and one of the wifi networks is very unstable on my laptop. This specific network have some different behaviors:

- Connects normally and I can use the internet for some days without problems
- Connects normally, but after some seconds or minutes it disconnects
- Connects to the network but without internet
- Refuses to connect on that network, but I can connect with the others
- This network disappears from list of available networks, but I can still see the others

This network is fine on other devices (mobile phones, smart tv) and other computers, the problem is just on my laptop.

This problem persists for more than one year.

I tried a lot of different solutions but none of them worked:

- Uninstalled wireless driver and installed the latest one (from 2015)
- Reset my computer and installed Windows 10 again
- Changed the DNS servers from auto to manual (tried with google's and another one)
- Reset the modem
- Changed the wifi channel on the modem settings
- Changed the security of the network from WPA2/WPA Personal to WPA2 Personal
- Used CMD commands like ipconfig /flushdns, netsh winsock reset, and many others

I think it may be some driver issue, but I have no idea of how to solve it.

Some info about my equipments:

- Computer: Acer aspire E5-573G
- Operating System: Windows 10 Home Single Language x64
- Network adapter: Qualcomm Atheros AR956x Wireless Network Adapter
- Modem: Sagemcom 5655v2

We have here at home a wifi repeater that my brother uses to connect to his desktop computer using a cable. This repeater seems to copy the wifi channel from our modem, I also don't know if this is a problem.